# Help identify ceiling board

Tags: ceiling, board

Recently a tree fell on my roof and some water got into the attic and dripped through cracks between the boards that make up my living room ceiling.

I've pulled and trashed the damp installation, but I am not sure whether or not to remove the boards. They appear to be coated with some kind of black plastic, and don't feel like drywall or other gypsum board, but I am no expert.

Any guesses about what they are made of and advice on the necessity of replacement?[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but note that you don't need to replace it if it's still sound and not severely moldy.

Comment: Are you sure there are boards , to me I would guess Sheetrock but if you can get the wet insulation out and it drys out ok I would agree with Isherwood, it may be fine left in place.

Comment: In the picture, there appears to be a seam. How is is joined? If it is joined with some sort of tuck tape - there are exterior use ones - could you not pull a little up a take look and see what is below it. I would think it is some sort of vapour barrier, then on the sheet rock.